# INSERT INTO, SELECT, and UPDATE on dup in the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update on duplicate key using insert and select.

```
INSERT INTO f_s.s_d_p(dom,title,lastupdated)
SELECT dom AS dDom,
COUNT(db2.rets.dom) AS dcount,
NOW() AS timeNow
FROM db2.rets
GROUP BY db2.rets.dom
LIMIT 5
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = dDom, last_updated = NOW();
```

but when I run the query I always get "unknown column dDom"

I tried set an alias for the select query but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use field name, not alias: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = db2.rets.dom, last_updated = NOW();` . Or do

```
INSERT INTO f_s.s_d_p(dom,title,lastupdated)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT dom AS dDom,
COUNT(db2.rets.dom) AS dcount,
NOW() AS timeNow
FROM db2.rets
GROUP BY db2.rets.dom
LIMIT 5)
a
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = a.dDom, last_updated = NOW();
```

Comment: what if i wanted to update using the count? could I do  KEY UPDATE title = a.dcount?